# Using wordpress with AJAX queries

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress, themes

I have built a custom theme for wordpress and I decided to use AJAX instead of just refreshing the page on each call. However, when I add the Wordpress loop to call in my data, it doesn't load at all, JS console doesn't give any errors. Any suggestions of why the content is not being called on AJAX call?

Comment: theres not much point asking a question without showing the code you used.

Comment: [See here for a thorough answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26950030/1922144)